# Duplicate results in Xpath and not CSS selectors in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

So I am playing around with scrapy through the [tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). I am trying to scrape the text, author and tags of each quote in the [companion website](http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/)
when using CSS selectors like mentioned there:

```
for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
    print quote.css('span.text::text').extract()
    print quote.css('span small::text').extract()
    print quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
```

I get the desired result (i.e: print of each text, author and quotes once).
But once using Xpath selectors like this:

```
for quote in response.xpath("//*[@class='quote']"):
    print quote.xpath("//*[@class='text']/text()").extract()
    print quote.xpath("//*[@class='author']/text()").extract()
    print quote.xpath("//*[@class='tag']/text()").extract()
```

I get duplicates results!

I still can't find why there is such a difference between the 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.//` instead of `//` for your relative searches e.g.

`print quote.xpath(".//*[@class='text']/text()").extract()`

When you use `//`, although you're searching from `quote`, it takes this to mean an absolute search so its context is still the root of the document. `.//` however, means to search from `.` - the current node - and the context of this search will be limited to the elements nested under `quote`.

As a side note, if you're looking to get the exact same results, you should consider changing `*` to the tags you used in the CSS search - `span` or `div`. In this case it doesn't make any difference but just a head's up for future reference.

Comment: Nice catch, didn't know about the `.//` thing!

Answer (score 1):

When you use // it will get all results from response. If you use .// then it scope will be limited to that selector. Try `.//` instead of `//`. It will solve your problem :-)